# Kernel function for use in Kernel-PCA given a known piecewise linear true data generating process

Tags: pca, kernel-trick

If I know that a multivariate dataset has a piecewise-linear data generating process with known knots (or breakpoints), then what is the appropriate kernel function to use in Kernel-PCA?

For example, given $n = 1, ..., N$ observations and $j = 1, ..., J$ variables, assume the true data generating process:
\begin{equation}
X_{n,j} = \alpha_{1,j} F_{n} I_{F_n \leq 0} + \alpha_{2,j} F_{n} I_{F_n > 0} + e_{n,j}
\end{equation}

where $I$ is an indicator function. That is, the true data generating process is piecewise linear in a single factor $F_n$, with a knot at $0$ and slopes $\alpha_{1,j}, \alpha_{2,j}$. Assuming I want to use Kernel-PCA, is there a known most efficient kernel function to use?

My guess is that the answer is probably related to the standard hinge function for piecewise-linear regression, i.e. $f(x) = \max(x, 0)$, and so the appropriate kernel function for Kernel-PCA might be some combination of the inner products of the centred variables and their hinge functions. But how would I derive this?

More generally, is there a standard methodology for converting a known true data generating process into the appropriate corresponding kernel function?

Any pointers to good reading on this material would also be greatly appreciated.